# onResume() not called second time an Activity is launched

Tags: android

During the normal course of development, I noticed that a particular activity appears to have stopped responding the second time it is called.

i.e. `menu->(intent)->activity->(back button)->menu->(intent)`

There is nothing relevant in logcat.

I don't even know where to start debugging this nor what code to show so here are the `onClick` and `onResume` fragments:

```
 if (!dictionary.getClassName().equals("")) {

            this.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent i;

                    i = new Intent(mContext, NVGlobeNavigatorVC.class);
                    i.putExtra("PAGE_TITLE", title);
                    i.putExtra("TITLE", _dictionary._title);

                    mContext.startActivity(i);

            });
        } else {
            findViewById(R.id.greaterthan).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

and in the Activity being launched:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    ...
```

Nothing unusual in manifest either:

```
<activity
    android:name=".NVViews.NVGlobeNavigatorVC"
    android:theme="@style/WindowTitleBackground"
    android:label="GlobeNavigator"/>
```

For clarity, I put breakpoints on `mContext.startActivity(i)` and `super.onResume()`.  I click the view with the `onClickListener` and both breakpoints are hit as expected.  I then press the back button which returns me to the menu.  `onPause()` is called as expected.

I touch the view to launch the activity again, and the breakpoint on `startActivity` is hit but not in `onResume()` in the target activity.  The screen goes black and the only way I can get going again is to restart the app.  If I pause the debugger, it pauses in `dalvik.system.NativeStart()` which implies that the activity is never relaunched.

I don't think it's relevant, but I'm using Intellij IDEA and have deleted all of the output directories, invalidated the caches and done a full rebuild.

Target API is 8.  I've tested on 2.3 and 4.0.4.

Any ideas?  I'm stumped.

[EDIT]

In `onPause`, I save some stuff to prefs.  The purpose of `onResume()` is to get them back again:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {

   super.onPause();

   SCPrefs.setGlobeViewViewPoint(globeView.getViewPoint());
   SCPrefs.setGlobeViewZoom(globeView.getZoom());
   SCPrefs.setGlobeViewScale(globeView.getScale());

    }
```

Comment: is second activity's oncreate called properly?

Comment: @StinePike It shouldn't be called if the `Activity` is in the background. Do you override `onPause()` and do anything in there?

Comment: @StinePike It isn't called, but I don't expect it to be since it's on the top of the stack and unlikely that Android will destroy my activity.

Comment: @codeMagic I do, I've edited..

Comment: @Simon why? Are you overriding backpressed? else your second activity will be finished and will be recreated second time. May be I am misunderstanding something

Comment: @StinePike [Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) He doesn't `finish()` the `Activity` so it doesn't call `onCreate()`

Comment: @StinePike  onCreate is only called the first time an activity is launched, by design - see the Activity life cycle documentation.   I'm not overriding back or calling finish().  I'm letting Android manage the activity stack entirely.  I've checked "don't keep activities" in developer options and then, onCreate() is called so i guess I have a workaround of using finish() but that sucks and I really want to understand what's happening.

Comment: I'm interested to know what's going on here, as I know you are. I'm stumped without seeing everything and knowing what else might be going on. Report back if you figure it out and I will look at it more over the weekend, also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem, and it's a bit esoteric.

I have a large static data structure which is loaded in a class static initialiser.  There was  a bug in that initialiser causing an infinite loop the second time it was called if the data structure was still loaded.

Because that class is referenced in my Activity, the class loader is loading it before `onCreate()` or `onResume()` is called.

The loop gave the appearance that the Activity loader had hung.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out.

Comment: So, Hhow exactly did you solve this problem, because i have EXACTLY the same issue.

Comment: @Rouz  As I said.  There was a bug in the static initialiser which was causing an infinite loop.  I fixed the bug, then it all worked.  The key is that the class loader is called before onCreate().

Answer (score 4):

This code:

```
i = new Intent(mContext, NVGlobeNavigatorVC.class);
```

creates a new intent.  The intent is of class `NVGlobeNavigatorVC.class`.

If you call it once, you create a new activity, lets call it "iTheFirst".  If you back out of the activity, it executes "on pause".  When you run the above code again, you create another new activity of the same class, but a different acitivity.  Hence it won't resume your other activity, but make a new one that we could call "iTheSecond".  It looks just like iTheFirst but is unique.

If you want to resume the above, after backing out of it, you need to keep a reference to it in your menu.  Then in your onClick, look to see if that activity exists, and if not, make a new one and start it, and if it does exist, just resume it.

Here is a sample activity that remembers and restarts an activity:

```
Intent savedCueCardActivity = null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, R.layout.landing);
}

public void goToNextScreen(View v) {
    if (savedCueCardActivity == null) {
        savedCueCardActivity = new Intent().setClass(this, CueCardActivity.class);
        startActivity(savedCueCardActivity);
        //       lastActivity.finish();
    } else {
        savedCueCardActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(savedCueCardActivity);
    }
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
}
```

Comment: I know all of this.  Please read the question. I'm not expecting to be working with the same instance. Regardless of whether the second time I launch the Activity is the same instance,  a new instance or the 40th instance, I still expect onResume to be called.  Oh, and for my app to not hang ;)

Comment: To be even more clear, `onResume()` should be called in every possible circumstance of an Activity coming to the foreground.  Additionally, my problem is that the app hangs, apparently in the DVM, with nothing relevant in logcat.  If I leave it without debugging, I eventually get an ANR so the main thread has stopped responding.

Comment: Sorry for being out of sync with your deeper question.  Your comments on your question led me to believe that you thought that you were getting your original activity back.  As I know that I get an onCreate() every time I make a new activity, as you are doing with i = newIntent.  This question has been really good for me for digging deeper into the activity lifecycle, so I really do appreciate it.
One other suggestion--before onCreate() is called, the initializations happen in the activity.  Are you doing anything odd there?  Have you overriden onCreate to see it called?

Comment: When onCreate() is called, everything works fine but I don't do anything interesting there.  Just set my contentView and get references to the UI elements.  Everything serious happens in onResume() or later.  I've got some ideas to try over the weekend and will come back if I find anything.  Thanks.

Comment: Yours was the only answer and one of your comments probably triggered my thought processes to dig into the class initialisations where the problem proved to lie.  Since I accepted my own answer, the bounty rep will disappear forever so I may as well award it to you.  Thanks.  +200

Comment: Thanks Simon, that is very kind of you!